# php-pgsql error in centOS

Tags: php, centos, repository

When trying to run:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-pgsql
```

I got the following error, why is this?

```
Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.5-1.el5.remi.1 is needed by package php-pgsql-5.3.5-1.el5.remi.1.x86_64 (remi)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall php:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi reinstall php
```

Then install php-pgsql:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-pgsql
```

If you install php from webtatic repo, first erase php and php-common:

```
yum erase php
yum erase php-common
```

Then install php from remi:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi --disablerepo=webtatic install php
```

Comment: if I do that then I'll be back with versio 5.1 right?

Comment: No, you install php 5.3 from REMI.

Comment: got it! I'll try and see if it works

Comment: I am getting this now when reinstalling:

Installed package php-5.3.5-1.1.w5.x86_64 not available.

Comment: 1) yum erase php 2) yum erase php-common 3)yum --enablerepo=remi --disablerepo=webtatic install php 4) yum --enablerepo=remi install php-pgsql